# Как запретить изменение заголовка окна?

Tags: delphi

Есть зловредная программа, которая переименовывает мои окна (в том числе и дочерние). Как можно не дать ей это сделать? Как сделать теоретически - знаю, но хотелось бы чуточку живого кода.

Заранее большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как запретить - не знаю, но можно попробовать мешать.
Идея такая - каждую секунду (может реже, нужно подумать), проверять свой заголовок. Как только он сменился - сразу менять назад. Для тестовой программы может и достаточно, но не для промышленного применения.

Идея поинтереснее. Поменять нам заголовок могут скорее всего просто посылкой WM_SETTEXT   (это собственно функция SetWindowText для других процессов и делает). Пишем свой обработчик и скорее всего теперь сможем перехватывать попытку изменить. Но мало чего, может они нам память правят.

Идея для ценителей. Рисуем заголовок самостоятельно. Читаем [здесь](http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2006/qt/draw_captionbar.htm) до полного понимания. Саму строку в памяти не держим, а генерируем по необходимости.

Comment: Переименовывать свои окошки - это не лучший способ, их несколько десятков (включая чилды).
Про то, что нужно играться с сообщением WM_SETTEXT - это я понимаю, но как это должно выглядеть на практике? Нужно бы, чтобы моё приложение не обрабатывало это сообщение от сторонних приложений(

Comment: начните с чтения например этой статьи http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/delphi/message-methods.html